# Dragon Dictate adding extra characters

Tags: macos, dragon-naturally-speaking

It seems that often at the end of the  It there will be an extra character or two. Often this is just some random letter. For example the S following the sentence was added by Dragon dictate. Is there some setting I can use to get rid of those? What about an extra space at the beginning a lign? S

Comment: which version of Drragon are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Dragon works much better if you run it in conjunction with [KnowBrainer](http://knowbrainer.com/), which resolves many of the issues Dragon has (and there are a lot).

If you use Dragon just as a tool to make your work more efficient, then you would have to buy KnowBrainer.  However, if you use it as an assistive technology aid due to a special need or diagnosis, they'll give you a free copy.

For example, I had no difficulty getting a free copy for my son, who has Tourette Syndrome and OCD, and loses a lot of time when typing due to a write-erase symptom.

---

Edit: Their website gives this as an introduction: "KnowBrainer 2016 is a third-party command utility that adds thousands of commands and numerous capabilities to Dragon, simplifies the learning curve and substantially increases your efficiency. KnowBrainer can even utilize built-in Windows speech recognition commands like DISPLAY Numbers which numbers every possible mouse click position so that you can left click, right click or double click any position with a single command. By comparison, the Dragon's MouseGrid command only works on 1 computer screen and can require up to 5 additional commands. From a command point of view, KnowBrainer is vastly superior to professional versions of Dragon which utilizes an older, limited and much slower command technology. KnowBrainer also includes an interactive ultra-dynamic sidebar that displays all available commands and doubles as a Command Browser. You can find or open any KnowBrainer command by saying FIND COMMAND or EDIT COMMAND .  Example: Say Edit Command to open the KnowBrainer Paragraph command for editing."  See http://shop.knowbrainer.com/store/pc/viewCategories.asp?idCategory=4

I believe they also have some promotional videos.

I did find Dragon easier to use with KnowBrainer installed on top.

My impression is that the Dragon software has not received much support since Nuance acquired it.  Or maybe that was the case even before the sale, I'm not sure.

Comment: Is there a list of issues that KnowBrainer is supposed to resolve?